# Elastic search how to analyze URL's / words with '-' in them

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm trying to figure out a way to analyze words/URLS with '-' in them. EX. "nnn999-9-prod-nnn9.test.com" | "Cisco-NX-4").

This means that "nnn999-" wont match anything, but "nnn999" or "nnn999-*" will, but I want "nnn999-" to also match.

I have tried standard analyzer and "uax_url_email" tokenizer but both parse it the same way giving the same tokens ["nnn999", "9", "prod", "nnn9", "test.com"]. The last thing I want to do is create a custom analyzer using regular expressions for each of the properties (10+).

Would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of the box, with default mapping, your example should work. It will use the same standard analyzer for both the index and the query, and so your query for "nnn999-" is transformed into "nnn999". For example:

Store document

```
POST my-index/_doc
{
  "test": "nnn999-9-prod-nnn9.test.com"
}
```

Search document

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "query": { "match": { "test": "nnn999-" } }
}
```

Result

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.2876821,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my-index",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "YXnNhGQBFtPd4lycLFbR",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "test": "nnn999-9-prod-nnn9.test.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It would be useful to see your index mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Effectively from the docs we could assume that is will work in your case but its not :(

Could the [whitespace tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/analysis-whitespace-tokenizer.html) do the job for you ?

```
GET _analyze
{
  "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
  "text" : "Cisco-NX-4 noise1 noise2 nnn999-9-prod-nnn9.test.com"
}

=>

{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "Cisco-NX-4",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 10,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "noise1",
      "start_offset": 11,
      "end_offset": 17,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "noise2",
      "start_offset": 18,
      "end_offset": 24,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "nnn999-9-prod-nnn9.test.com",
      "start_offset": 25,
      "end_offset": 52,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    }
  ]
}
```